# VBA sum loops in Formula Arrays

Tags: excel, vba

If I have defined named ranges for some blocks - say for example, 2 by 2 blocks named Apple1, Apple2, Apple3, Apple4

and I want to create a Total Block being the sum of the above (in excel, the formula array formula would be {Apple1 + Apple2 + Apple3 + Apple4}
With the FormulaArray command - am I on the right lines in my thought process below?

```
For i = 1 to 2
range("Total").formulaarray = "=" & "Apple" & i
next i
```

Answer (score 1):

I've not  understand why you need `FormulaArray` for such task, but you can use this:

```
Sub test()
    Dim i%, Apples$
    For i = 1 To 4
        Apples = Apples & "+SUM(Apple" & i & ")"
    Next i
    [Total].FormulaArray = "=" & Mid(Apples, 2, Len(Apples))
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: thank you, i will give this a go. Note, the formulaarray is because i want the 
"Total" to be an 2x2 array as well.

Comment: @psw very valuable comment, I've understand your point (`{=SUM(a+b+c)}`), but answer has been posted to show the way of how to put values to array formula, not for give a best possible way to solve the issue of the author. have no idea what behind the OP needs.

Comment: @Vasily,  I do not understand your point.  Since you use `Sum` function, why do you use `a+b+c`?  If `a+b+c` is used, `Sum` is redundant.

Comment: @pwc `{=SUM(a+b+c)}` where a,b,c named ranges, e.g.  `{=SUM(Apple1+Apple2+Apple3)}`

Comment: @Vasily, Why not use `{=a+b+c}`?  It is brevity.

Comment: @pwc because `a` can be equal to range of cells, e.g. `A1:A10`, it means `{=SUM(A1:A10+B1:B10+C1:C10)}`

Comment: @Vasily,  There is a drawback in `{=Sum(Apple1+Apple2+Apple3)}`.  If any cells in Apple1, Apple2, or Apple3 are string, it will return `#VALUE!` error.  But my soluate `{=Sum(Apple1,Apple2,Apple3)}` will not.

Comment: @pcw `{=Sum(Apple1,Apple2,Apple3)}` does not need array formula, it will give same results without `{}`. Once again, anwer have been posted just to show how to put values to array, not for give a best possible way to solve the issue of the author.

Answer (score 1):

After my experiment, I find the behavior of `FormulaArray` is more complicated.

```
sub test()
    dim i as long, Apples1 as variant, Apples2 as variant

    for i = 1 to 3
        Apples1 = Apples1 & "Apple" & i & "+"
        Apples2 = Apples2 & "Apple" & i & ","
    next i

    range("total1").FormulaArray = "=sum(" & left(Apples1, len(Apples1)-1) & ")"
    range("total2").FormulaArray = "=sum(" & Apples2 & ")"
    range("total3").FormulaArray = "=" & left(Apples1, len(Apples1)-1)
end sub
```

the outcome is 
[image]

If any cells in Apple1, Apple2 or Apple3 are string, the outcome is
[image]